# Onedrive uploading fails with the Internal Server Error

Tags: php, wordpress, api, rest, onedrive

I'm trying to create file on the OneDrive using REST API with PHP, but in the response I retrieve HTTP status code 500.

Code:
`

```
    $url = $this->buildUrl(
        '{folder_id}/files/{filename}?access_token={token}',
        array(
            'folder_id' => $folderId,
            'filename'  => $filename,
            'token'     => $this->getAccessToken(),
        )
    );

    $response = wp_remote_request($url, array(
        'body'    => $content,
        'method'  => 'PUT',
    ));
```

`

Error message from the response body: 
An error occurred while performing the action. Try again later.

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have the correct base url for the OneDrive API: https://apis.live.net/v5.0/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just went through the same problem. It worked for me when I removed 'Content-type' line from request header.

If you are using PHP Curl to send request in wp_remote_request, you can remove 'Content-type' line from request header by calling something similar to this, before calling curl_exec:

```
 curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type:"));
```

By adding the code above, the actual request header looks like this (note there is no 'Content-Type'):

```
 PUT /v5.0/{folderId}/files/{filename}?access_token={accesstoken}
 User-Agent: SOMEAGENT
 Host: apis.live.net
 Accept: */*
 Expect: 100-continue
 Content-Length: 29
```

---

FYI: I got a hint from here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn631834.aspx

"For a PUT request, leave the Content-Type blank and put the contents of the file in the request body."

Hope it helps.